# Spring boot redireccionar a una tab concreta

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, thymeleaf

Tengo una web con diferentes pestañas en la pág. de inicio. Al pasar por el controlador quiero que se situe en la pestaña correcta que es la de administración, pero no me funciona. Esta es el return que indico:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/#busqueda-administracion");
```

**EDITADO**

El HTML es muy extenso, añado una parte:

```
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab12">

                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                      <!-- Default panel contents -->
                                      <div class="panel-heading">Entregas > Flujos de Entregas</div>
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        <p>Flujos de Entregas</p>
                                      </div>
                                    
                                      <!-- Table -->
                                      <table class="table">
                                          <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th scope="col">#</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Flujos</th>
                                              
                                            </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th scope="row">1</th>
                                              <td>Flujo EDC</td>
                                              
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th scope="row">2</th>
                                              <td>Flujo EIN</td>
                                              
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th scope="row">3</th>
                                              <td>Flujo CERT</td>
                                              
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        
                                        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                                          <ul class="pagination">
                                            <li>
                                              <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                              </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                              <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                              </a>
                                            </li>
                                          </ul>
                                        </nav>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

El caso es que no funciona devolver el Modelo con el redirect y la pestaña, alguien sabe si se tiene que hacer con Javascript? cómo se haría?

Entiendo que gestionar una web y cargar en la misma pestaña varios paneles está a la orden del día, alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Deberías agregar tu HTML, lo mas probable es que tengas que utilizar javascript para manipular los tabs

Comment: Para redireccionar debes poner un return "redirect:" con la pagina a la cual quieres redireccionar

Comment: Efectivamente, se debería hacer con javascript. En cuanto a cómo se hace... no hacemos tutoriales, y lo que preguntas ya se ha hecho (y comentado aquí en SO) múltiples veces. Investiga un poco

Comment: Benito tu comentario no aporta nada, ya he buscado en los foros y probado las respuestas que se indican y no me ha funcionado, por eso insisto.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno pues ya he dado con la solución por si le puede servir a alguien:

1. En el controlador pasar 2 variables, una indicando la pestaña y otra el "tab", "panel", etc dentro que se desea seleccionar.

   ```
    model.addObject("pestana", "administracion");
    model.addObject("subapartado", "flujoentregas");
   ```
2. En la vista con Thymeleaf recuperar esas variables y si son equal al div ponerlas active:

   class="tab-pane" id="tab1" th:classappend="${subapartado eq 'tipoentregas'} ? 'active' : ''"